# How to connect a DB using Oracle DataProvider DB on .Net Core?

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm migrating a.net application to .net Core and I cannot establish a simple connection to Oracle database using the DataProvider in the same way.

Startup.cs connection :

```
OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add("DB", "Data Source=DB;enlist=true;User Id=**;Password=**;credentialId=**");
```

DataAccess class using ProxyProvider:

```
 [ProxyProvider("DB")]
    public class DataAcces : BaseProxy, IDataAcces
    {
        public virtual string GetParameter(string parameter)
        {
            Parametro user = null;

            try
            {
                var request = new GetParameterRequest { Parameter = parameter };
                var listResult = Provider.GetFirst<ParameterResponse>(CommandType.StoredProcedure, request);
```

Request:

```
 [ProcedureRequest("SP_GetParameter", Package = "PKG_General_Parameters")]
        internal class GetParameterRequest : IProcedureRequest
        {
```

The Provider. always throw an error like that there is no connection available.

Is there any way to using DataProvider like this on .net Core?